# Is there a way to paste a link into an external cell to be used to import data from?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Currently, I am using the function "=IMPORTHTML("", "table", number). This requires for the data to be displayed on an additional sheet. I am wondering if it would be possible for a link to be pasted on an external cell, then using this formula to display the data on the additional sheet. Instead of having to paste the link directly into the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IMPORTHTML(A1, "table", 1)
```

where A1 cell has your link